# difference between Page_Init vs OnInit

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I had an interview a week ago and one of the questions was what the difference between OnInit, Page_Init and PreRender. which one is preferable?

Comment: Preferrable for what? Also, wouldn't the ASP.NET docs cover this?

Comment: And, off the top of my head, `OnInit()` will fire even if you turn off auto event wire up. That said, `OnXxx()` methods should arguably be used to change the logic for whether / how to raise an event, not to handle it. (Although it's mostly a wash.) It also lets you do something *before* the regular `OnInit()` logic, but then again your code's correct behaviour shouldn't depend on those timing details, seems very fragile to me. I've no idea why `PreRender` would be mentioned, it's on the opposite side of the page rendering lifecycle and should be used for vastly different purposes.

Comment: Are you sure the question wasn't what is the difference between `Page_Init`, `Page_Load` and `Page_PreRender`?

Answer (score 4):

`Page_Init` is an event handler for the `Page.Init` event, you typically see it if you add a handler within the class itself.

`OnInit` is a method that raises the `Init` event.

The two can be seen as being equivalent *if used within a subclass*, but there is a difference: only `Init` is exposed to other types, the `OnInit` method is protected and is responsible for raising the event, so if you override `OnInit` and fail to call `base.OnInit` then the `Init` event won't be fired. Here's how it looks like:

```
public class Page {

    public event EventHandler Init;
    public event EventHandler Load;

    protected virtual void OnInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if( this.Init != null ) this.Init(sender, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if( this.Load != null ) this.Load(sender, e);
    }

    public void ExecutePageLifecylce() {
        this.OnInit();
        // do some houskeeping here
        this.OnLoad();
        // further housekeeping
        this.Dispose();
    }
}

public class MyPage : Page {

    public MyPage() {

        this.Init += new EventHandler( MyPage_Init );
    }

    private void MyPage_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // No additional calls are necessary here
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // you must make this following call for any .Load event handlers to be called
        base.OnLoad(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Generally overriding the `OnLoad` / `OnInit` methods is faster (but this is a microptimisation, you're only saving a couple of extra instructions for delegate dispatch) and many "purists" will argue using events unnecessarily is just ugly :)

Another advantage of not using events is avoiding bugs caused by `AutoEventWireUp` which can cause events to be called twice for each page load, which obviously is not desirable if your event-handlers are not idempotent.