# What is Difference between Page-Init and OnInit (page life cycle) Method ?

Tags: c#, asp.net

//when i write both method then Oninit method gets call every time  or when i write only Page_Init method then only page_init gets called. anyone knows difference between them?

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708295/difference-between-page-init-vs-oninit> Read it

Comment: @faizan . . didnt work for me.. i want more explanation